# React Navigation remove previous route and go to double previous?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens

```
----settingsScreen
   ----ActivationScreen
       -----WelcomeScreen
```

So, in this user will first got to setting screen and the they will go to Activation screen.

In this, welcome screen, i have a button saying "Activate" and when user clicks this, i need to navigate to WelcomeScreen, but when user tries to go back they should go to settingScreen instead of ActivationScreen - How to achive this ?

```
I tried this:
                   const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                            index: 0,
                                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SettingScreen'})],
                            });
                     this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But, its resetting the whole stack and exits the app when i press back at welcome screen !

Please help, and am using React Navigation 4

Comment: Use navigation.pop() to go to the previous screen

Comment: I dont need to go to previous screen, i need to go before that, i mean previous's previous screen !

Comment: Try using "NavigationActions" instead of "StackActions"

Comment: Nothing is happening

Comment: And NavigationActions doent have reset right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating this way will navigate you to SettingsScreen. If the screen isn't in stack then It will push in stack and if It's already in stack then It will navigate you to that screen

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen');
```

Comment: I think, you havent understood my question !

Comment: You didn't clear your question. I answered, what I understood. You said you have 2 screens in above post while you written 3 screens. What I understood is that, You have 3 screens like A - B - C and user is on screen C and tried to navigate back so default it will navigate to screen B but you wanted to navigate user to screen A? Is that you wanted?

Comment: yes right, A ( Tab ), B & C (stack) ! So, when user clicks on activate button on Screen B - it should navigate to Screen C ( But when user clicks on back arrow or hardware back button it should go back to Screen A )

Comment: "A" itself a screen or just TAB which has 2 screens (stackNavigator) - (B&C)? Go to this link there https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating/

Comment: A is an stack inside Tab, and B&C are just stack !